# Xcode: Swift version of project vs. Swift version of cocoa pods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa

I am writing an iOS app in Xcode and it's all working fine. However, I have always wondered why it is that in build settings of my project I can specify a Swift language version, and I can also specify one for each cocoa pod. Can these really be specified independently?

Also, I have recently changed the Swift version of my project from 3.3 to 4.1, but this change did not affect the Swift language setting in the cocoa pods (which was still shown as 3.3). However, when manually changing the Swift language version of one of the pods to 4.1, everything still ran fine.

Is there a risk that if I use a cocoa pod which is not updated in time for the release of new Swift versions that this then causes problems as I cannot update the Swift version of the whole project when I want?

Anyway, I just can't make sense of the relationship but am really interested in the answer and would love to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The version of the Swift language that the compiler uses is configured independently as a build setting for *each target* in your project.

And this makes sense for the very reason your example presupposes: you might be using a framework whose language version is different from your main app target's language version.